# warning errors in php

Tags: php, include, warnings

I am starting to work on a site that has been up for some time. It is producing the following error messages before I even got started:

`Warning: main(includes/main_functions.php) [function.main]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \\boswinfs01\home\users\web\b748\ez.paphospro\includes\top.php on line 22`

`Warning: main() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/main_functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\4\pear') in \\boswinfs01\home\users\web\b748\ez.paphospro\includes\top.php on line 22`

`Warning: main(includes/functions/functions_email.php) [function.main]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \\boswinfs01\home\users\web\b748\ez.paphospro\includes\top.php on line 23`

`Warning: main() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/functions/functions_email.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;c:\php\4\pear') in \\boswinfs01\home\users\web\b748\ez.paphospro\includes\top.php on line 23`

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function: get_includes_file() in \\boswinfs01\home\users\web\b748\ez.paphospro\includes\top.php on line 24`

Could it be that the path in the includes\top.php file is incorrect? Or do I need to look for something else?

the top.php file includes the following code: 
    `define('BASE_PATH' , '/--/--/--/--/--/--/');` (I took out the path in this example).

and on the lines 22, 23, 24 it has the following code:

```
 `include("includes/main_functions.php");
  include("includes/functions/functions_email.php");
  include(get_includes_file("includes/config.php"));`
```

all the above files are on the server in those directories.

I really need some direction as to why the errors are there and what I can do to fix them.

Thanks for any and all help or suggestions.

Comment: check the directory structure and the file permissions.

Comment: Why don't you try to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and get the path?

Comment: as top.php is under includes you probably should include the files without the include in the url

  `include("./main_functions.php");`
  `include("./functions/functions_email.php");`
  `include(get_includes_file("./config.php"));`

Comment: The directory structure seems to be correct and the file permissions are set at 755.

Comment: I changed the lines in top.php to
include("main_function.php");

Comment: I changed the lines in top.php to
include("main_function.php");include("functions/functions_email.php");include("config.php"); That took out most of the errors. Now the only error that shows is :Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class config in c:\php\4\pear\Config.php on line 44 I am admittedly not a php programmer, so your suggestion and answers have been really helpful so far. Someone else before me created this website and the php code to run it. I'm just trying to maintain it.

Comment: This error seems to be cleared up, the site is working now. Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The warning is caused by non existing script file or wrong file permissions.

I would recommend you to do some refactoring, replacing the include function with [require_once](https://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php). This way you'll get a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR level error which is better than a misleading application.

Then you must define your application base path `define('DOCROOT', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);` and use it to reference all other application dependencies (e.g. `require_once(DOCROOT.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'includes'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'main_functions.php');`